# How can I set autoGenerate in the primaryKeys list of @Entity?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-room

I'm new for the Android Room library. I want to create a table with two primary key. I also want to set autoGenerate to these two primary key but I don't know how to do it. The detail of the code is shown below:

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = {"userId", "planName"},
    foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = User.class,
    parentColumns = "id",
    childColumns = "userId",
    onDelete = CASCADE))
public class Plan {

    public int userId;

    @NonNull
    public String planName;
}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Technically you can't have 2 primary keys. It's by definition a single index which has `UNIQUE` constraint on it. Although it can be applied to 2 columns at once. Meaning that the combination of those 2 columns should be unique but each one separately can contain repetitive values.

And as for the `autoGenerate`, a primary key can only be auto generated if it is of type `integer` and a single column. You can't have a composite primary key be auto generated.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, a primary key should be a single column that uniquely identifies each row. If you want to also guarantee the uniqueness of the pair (userId, planName), you should just add a UNIQUE constraint. Additionally, you may want to add an index to the pair of columns.